# Count the number of rows in a related table within a single row main table in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Help me little. I use laravel Query Builder. I have posts and related replies table. I need total number of replies in the post(not use get(), use first() or find()).

```
$post= DB::table('posts')
            ->leftJoin('replies', 'posts.id', '=', 'replies.post_id')
            ->select(
                'posts.id',
                'posts.slug',
                'posts.title',
                'posts.body',
                'posts.created_at',
            DB::raw('COUNT(replies.id) AS total_replies'),
            )
            ->where('posts.id', $post->id)->first();
```

Is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have written `$port->id` instead of `$post->id` so you need to fix that.

Then, assuming you have defined the relationship between the Post and Reply models, and you have an instance of the Post model (let's call it `$post`), you can count the related replies like this.

```
$totalReplies = $post->replies()->count();
```

Make sure you have defined the relationship in your Post model. For example, if you have a hasMany relationship between posts and replies...

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }
}
```

This will return the total number of replies associated with the `$post` instance without writing complex SQL queries.

If you haven't defined models for your posts and replies tables, and you are working with raw SQL queries using Laravel's Query Builder, you can count the total number of replies for a specific post using a subquery.

```
$postId = 1; // Replace whatever id

$post = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(
        'posts.id',
        'posts.slug',
        'posts.title',
        'posts.body',
        'posts.created_at',
        DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM replies WHERE replies.post_id = posts.id) AS total_replies')
    )
    ->where('posts.id', $postId)
    ->first();
```

Comment: Karl changed but not working

Comment: Do you have a hasMany relationship between Post and Reply models? If so you can do $totalReplies = $post->replies()->count();.

Comment: yesterday I read article that Query Builder faster than Eloquent so I use query. what do you think?

Comment: I would define your models.

Comment: Thank you Karl. that's what I was looking for.